# Symfony denyAccessUnlessGranted in Controller constructor

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I have a controller with many actions:

```
class SomeController extends AbstractController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_SUPERMANAGER');
        [...]
    }

    public function someAjaxAction()
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_SUPERMANAGER');
        [...]
    }
    
    public function someOtherAjaxAction()
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_SUPERMANAGER');
        [...]
    }
}
```

Why I can't just do this, to deny access in all the actions of that controller?

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_SUPERMANAGER');
}
```

I got `Call to a member function has() on null` on AbstractController.php:218:

```
if (!$this->container->has('security.authorization_checker')) {
```

Is there any way to do that in the controller class, besides a rule in `security.yaml`?

Comment: Take a look at the source code for AbstractController.  The answer as to why you can't do things in a controller's constructor will be obvious.  Just about every Symfony developer has to go through this rite of passage.  You can use the access control section in security.yaml  or perhaps a controller event listener to accomplish the same same thing.

Comment: I want to understand "the answer to why you can't do things in a controller's constructor". It's not at all obvious to me after looking at the source code for AbstractController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle's [isGranted annotation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code) at class level like this:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;

/**
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_SUPERMANAGER")
**/
class SomeController extends AbstractController
{
   // Your actions without auth check in each
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FrameworkExtraBundle is deprecated according to Symfony and its use is discouraged. It is possible to do the same thing with Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\IsGranted. This is a good article that helped me https://nebkam.medium.com/symfony-deprecated-route-and-method-annotations-4d5e1d34556a

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also that blog post is not relevant at all since it's from 2018... Probably some bot building seo links